# Language which is recursively enumerable but not recursive

Tags: turing-machines, automata

Can someone provide me with some examples of languages which are recursively enumerable but are not recursive. I know that there exist some languages which are not Recursive but recursively enumerable but couldn't find such examples anywhere.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard example is the halting problem – the language of all descriptions of Turing machines which halt on the empty input.